# Get name of styleable attribute programmatically

Tags: android, attributes

Is there a way to programmatically get name of styleable attribute:

```
<declare-styleable name="TextView">
    <attr name="DataContext" format="string" />
    <attr name="Text" format="string" />
</declare-styleable>
```

For example I want to get `"Text"` from `R.styleable.TextView_Text` integer value.

Answer (score 2):

Your Styleable is:

```
<declare-styleable name="TextView">
    <attr name="DataContext" format="string" />
    <attr name="Text" format="string" />
</declare-styleable>
```

Call it where you want with this:

```
custom:DataContext="@string/xxxx"
```

In your Code:

```
TypedArray a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.TextView);


  int n = a.getIndexCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int attr = a.getIndex(i);
        switch (attr) {
        case R.styleable.TextView_DataContext:
            title = a.getString(attr);
            break;

        case R.styleable.TextVie_Text:
            //Any you want
            break;
        default:
            Log.d("TAG", "Unknown attribute for " + getClass().toString() + ": " + attr);
            break;
        }
    }

    a.recycle();
```